# python PyTest lask for login page for each Test module

Tags: python, pytest, seleniumbase

I am new to python. I have requirement that login must be done before running the all the test. i.e. on  class level.
if i have two test file TEST_F1 , TEST_F2   then when i run the test  the login page popup and  after successful login it must run all the test in TEST_F1 . When it start to run TEST_F2   then login page must popup again to validate.
I am using python , Pytest ,slenumnbase lib

I was not able to archive this in python. It works for me in C# selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fixture to handle the login logic and use it in your test classes.

Here's an example:

**Create a fixture for login in conftest.py:**

```
# conftest.py

import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def login(request):

    username = request.cls.username
    password = request.cls.password
    print(f"Logging in with username: {username} and password: {password}")

    def logout():
        print("Logging out...")
    request.addfinalizer(logout)
```

**Use the login fixture in your test classes:**

```
# test_module.py

import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("login")
class TestF1:
    username = "user1"
    password = "pass1"

    def test_f1_1(self):
        # Your test logic for TEST_F1_1(using self.username and self.password)

    def test_f1_2(self):
        # Your test logic for TEST_F1_2

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("login")
class TestF2:
    username = "user2"
    password = "pass2"

    def test_f2_1(self):
        # Your test logic for TEST_F2_1 
    def test_f2_2(self):
        # Your test logic for TEST_F2_2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to pass different username and password from each test class , how can i do that ?

Comment: You can modify the login fixture to accept parameters (username and password) in the conftest.py file and In each test class (TestF1 and TestF2) you need to add class attributes username and password with specific values for that class.